# Passing props to dynamically loaded components

Tags: reactjs

```
export const Menus = {
    user1: {
        userMenu: <User1Menu />
    },
    user2: {
        userMenu: <User2Menu />
    }
};



render() {
...
// I want to pass props to <User1Menu /> ?
{Menus[user1].userMenu}
}
```

I have such a situation where I have to pass props to components dynamically. I tried `withProps() from recompose` but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your components in a function which will receive and propagate props..

```
export const Menus = {
    user1: {
        userMenu: (props) => <User1Menu {...props}/>
    },
    user2: {
        userMenu: (props) => <User2Menu {...props}/>
    }
};



render() {
...
// I want to pass props to <User1Menu /> ?
{Menus['user1'].userMenu({prop1: 'prop1value', prop2: 'prop2value'})}
}
```

Comment: Its complaining about the missing component display name

Comment: i havent tested the above code, might be a small issue, i can help if you can share the repo

Answer (score 3):

Use the dot notation: `Menus.user1.userMenu` or use the string notation: `Menus["user1"].userMenu`

You cannot use `Menus[user1].userMenu` until you have a variable named `user1`.

I suggest doing the below, it reduces the object traversal by a step (`Menus.user1` or `Menus["user1"]`)!

```
export const Menus = {
  user1: <User1Menu />,
  user2: <User2Menu />
};
```

Updated Answer:

You can pass the props you need as function param like this, and can thereby pass the prop to the component.

```
export const Menus = {
    user1: (yourProps) => <User1Menu ...yourProps />
    user2: (yourProps) => <User2Menu ...yourProps />
});
```

for example, you can make an object out of the props you are going to pass:

```
const yourPropsThatYourePassingToComponent = {
  onChange: (param) => this.onChange(param),
  arrayOfObj: [{ key1:"val1" }, { key2:"val2" }],
  fetchSomething: this.props.fetchSomething
};
```

and pass it to the component in Menus like this: `Menus.user1(yourPropsThatYourePassingToComponent)`.

Comment: The sample is for demonstration purpose only. The real problem is passing the props here. Can you please edit your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the key in quotes e.g.

```
Menus["user1"].userMenu
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer the real problem of passing props.